# Nginx Open Socket Left Connection Error Django

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx

when I first published my Django project, the index page was showing, but when I clicked anywhere, it did not redirect to the page. The error I'm getting against the request is Server Error(500)

I reset the system, I restarted nginxi, this time the index page started not to come.

nginx error.log is error

```
2094#2094: *19 open socket #10 left in connection 4
```

I couldn't find many resources about this problem on the internet.
Can anyone help me?

```
    /etc/nginx/sites-available/lordplus
    
      GNU nano 4.8                                                                                         /etc/nginx/sites-available/lordplus
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    root /var/www/lordplus; # Projenin kök dizini

    location /static/ {
    }

    location /media/ {
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/lordplus/lordplus.sock;

    }
}
```

And here Gunicorn Service

```
/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                                        /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=runadmingen
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/lordplus
ExecStart=/var/www/lordplus/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/www/lordplus/lordplus.sock lordplus.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```